# Custom contrasts in lmer to a "no-change" condition

Tags: mixed-model, contrasts

I'm using lmer to look at the interaction between continuous variable `baseline` and grouping factor `condition` (8 levels) on continuous variable outcome `post`. There's a significant interaction between baseline and condition.

Some of the slopes, e.g., ConditionR concha 25:Baseline, are significantly different from the reference level.  Reference level is currently set at ConditionL concha 25:Baseline. However, instead of comparing each condition to another, is there a way of comparing each condition to another slope which is not in the data? I want to see if each condition is different from a pretend "no-change" condition, where Post ~ Baseline, i.e., the dotted diagonal slope on the graph. Is this possible?

```
model <- lmer(Post ~ Condition*Baseline + 
                   (1|Participant), data = SCT, REML=FALSE)

> summary(SCT_lmer)
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's method [
lmerModLmerTest]
Formula: Post ~ Condition * Baseline + (1 | Participant)
   Data: SCT

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   -21.3     25.6     28.7    -57.3       82 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.8517 -0.5388 -0.1858  0.5219  3.6633 

Random effects:
 Groups      Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Participant (Intercept) 0.006808 0.08251 
 Residual                0.028768 0.16961 
Number of obs: 100, groups:  Participant, 15

Fixed effects:
                              Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                   -0.01470    0.09361 81.40094  -0.157  0.87558    
ConditionR concha 25           0.11921    0.13024 78.86407   0.915  0.36281    
ConditionL canal 25            0.10321    0.12449 74.54257   0.829  0.40971    
ConditionR canal 25            0.20555    0.12622 76.31627   1.628  0.10754    
ConditionL concha 80           0.17797    0.11728 78.88503   1.518  0.13313    
ConditionR concha 80           0.21205    0.12641 66.35342   1.678  0.09815 .  
ConditionL canal 80            0.05414    0.13051 83.44101   0.415  0.67934    
ConditionR canal 80            0.19836    0.13196 84.16656   1.503  0.13653    
Baseline                       1.29557    0.19035 91.74325   6.806 1.01e-09 ***
ConditionR concha 25:Baseline -0.51711    0.25932 96.94480  -1.994  0.04894 *  
ConditionL canal 25:Baseline  -0.37673    0.24675 92.86251  -1.527  0.13023    
ConditionR canal 25:Baseline  -0.70992    0.30560 88.25439  -2.323  0.02248 *  
ConditionL concha 80:Baseline -0.60252    0.28323 92.07380  -2.127  0.03607 *  
ConditionR concha 80:Baseline -0.82504    0.24608 70.96949  -3.353  0.00129 ** 
ConditionL canal 80:Baseline  -0.31345    0.26524 99.68897  -1.182  0.24010    
ConditionR canal 80:Baseline  -0.78126    0.26038 96.90995  -3.000  0.00343 **
```

[image: Interaction]